# Error: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: indices[3,7] = -1 is not in [0, 20000)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am training a lstm on a ecommerce data. During training I am getting following error:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:
>   indices[3,7] = -1 is not in [0, 20000)     [[Node: embedding_1/GatherV2
>   = GatherV2[Taxis=DT_INT32, Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training/Adam/gradients/embedding_1/GatherV2_grad/Reshape"],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](embedding_1/embeddings/read,
>   embedding_1/Cast, lstm_1/TensorArrayUnstack/range/start)]]

Any idea how to resolve this issue?
I define my model as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 128))
model.add(LSTM(128, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
print('Train...')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=2, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score, acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made following changes in the code and it worked:

I used python.cat.codes for this

```
for i in range(len(columns)):
    df[columns[i]] = df[columns[i]].astype('category')
    df[columns[i]+"_cat"] = df[columns[i]].cat.codes
```

the astype converts the data columns to category type, hence, solving the problem.